# Max function used with nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as follows

```
lis1={{{1,5,6},{4,7,8}},{{1,2,2},{5,6,7}}}
```

and would like to calculate the max value of each nested list in order to get following result

```
lis2={{6,8},{2,7}}
```

Does anyone have a hint. Thanks

Comment: you can use `Map[Max,list,level]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Apply[Max, lis1, {2}]
(*  {8, 7}  *)
```

If the list has varying depths, then

```
lis1 /. v_?VectorQ :> Max[v]
(* {{6, 8}, {2, 7}}  *)
```

For example

```
{{{1, 5, 6}, {{{4, 7, 8}}}}, {{{1, 2, 2}}, {5, 6, 7}}} /.  v_?VectorQ :> Max[v]
(*  {{6, {{8}}}, {{2}, 7}}  *)
```

---

If `lis1` is a large packed array, then `ReplaceAll`, `Apply` and `Map` will unpack it.  In that case one can compile `Map`:

```
On["Packing"];
Compile[{{x, _Integer, 3}}, Map[Max, x, {2}]] @
 RandomInteger[100, {10, 2, 3}]
Off["Packing"];
(*
  {{90, 45}, {90, 82}, {81, 77}, {72, 96}, {87, 35},
   {72, 97}, {74, 61}, {56, 69}, {78, 99}, {77, 92}}
*)
```

Or packaged in a function:

```
paMax[a_?Developer`PackedArrayQ] := With[{level = ArrayDepth[a]},
  Compile[{{x, _Integer, level}}, Map[Max, x, {-2}]][a]]

paMax[RandomInteger[100, {10, 2, 3}]]
(*
  {{70, 85}, {93, 81}, {49, 20}, {80, 86}, {98, 80},
   {86, 69}, {47, 98}, {82, 88}, {77, 66}, {93, 88}}
*)
```

Comment: It is my first  time to see the usage of `On["Packing"];Off["Packing"];`. Then I search the *Documentation*, but I didn't discover the information about it. So could you give me some ditails about it? Thanks sincerely:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang It's described briefly in the docs for `On`.  They turn on and off the group of messages that warns the user when a packed array is unpacked.  (It does not help the code run better.)

Answer (score 4):

```
Max @@@ # & /@ lis1
(* {{6, 8}, {2, 7}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
Max@# & /@ lis1[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@lis1
```

or, as Belisarius said,

```
Map[Max, lis1, #] & /@ Range@Length@lis1
```

or, for something like

```
lis1 = {{1, 2, 3}, {{{{{25, 5, 4}}}}}, {{{4, 5, 6}}}, {{5, 10, 7}}};
```

you can use

```
Replace[lis1, x__ :> Max@x, 1]

(*{3, 25, 6, 10}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{{1, 5, 6}, {4, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {5, 6, 7}}};
```

**1.**

With `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2)

```
ArrayReduce[Max, list, 3]
```

{{6, 8}, {2, 7}}

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[%]
```

True

**2.**

With `AggregationLayer` (new in 11.1)

```
Round @ AggregationLayer[Max, 3] @ list
```

{{6, 8}, {2, 7}}

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[%]
```

True

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy` and `Max`:

```
lis1 = {{{1, 5, 6}, {4, 7, 8}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {5, 6, 7}}};

Keys@GroupBy[lis1, Max /@ # &]

(*{{6, 8}, {2, 7}}*)
```